# ListActivity list does not refresh properly when in full screen?

Tags: android, listview

I am using a ListActivity to display an iconified list (using a custom implementation of BaseAdapter). It does not reload data properly. When I change the contents of the adapter and notify the list, it appears that the old data draws on top of the new data, until a scroll event happens. The old rows draw on top of the new rows, but the old rows disappear when I start scrolling.

However if I set the ListActivity style to Theme.Dialog, it refreshes fine. (presumably because when in dialog, the activity resizes each time the list contents changes, which forces a redraw of the whole view hiearchy?)

Any ideas how to make this work in my fullscreen activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, if I set a background color, everything refreshes properly.  Without the background color, I get the refresh issues I described in the original post.

Comment: seems logical. if you have a background color, it force to redraw everything. Though if you have a background with transparency your problem may be present. Have you tried to set a color to something invisible. color #00ffffff

Comment: any idea how to force it to redraw without a background?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to call invalidate() on your listView?

Here are some function you could try:

```
invalidate()
requestLayout()
forceLayout()
```

You could even do that, when your thing is iconified( I don't exactly what you mean by that). You could set the adapter of the view to null or an empty adapter. Something empty just enough to not make your activity crash. Then when you want to display your ListView just set the adapter back to it.

That could be linked to drawing cache but it would be good if you could give us some more information.

Comment: Yes, I've tried invalidate() and invalidateViews() (both from a ui thread).

Comment: In onRestart() clear the content of listview.                       Have you tried with notifyDataSetChaned().